# Grails, injecting/populating domain object with value from session

Tags: data-binding, grails

In my application many classes have common field 'company'. When application saves that objects, they must be filled with company (there is validation for that). Company is also kept in a session. Now, when I want to use domain class as a command object, company must be already filled or I get validation error. Is there any way to always fill company field, before any validation happens, so that I didn't have to do it manually every time.
(I tried custom data binder, but it does not work when there is no parameter in a request)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set the property just before the object is saved, updated or validated using the [GORM events](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#eventsAutoTimestamping) `beforeInsert`, `beforeUpdate` or `beforeValidate`.

In your domain you need something like that:

```
import org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextHolder 
class Foo {
    String company
    ...
    def beforeInsert = {
        try {
            // add some more error checking (i.e. if there is is no request)
            def session = RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes().getSession()
            if(session) {
                this.company = session.company
            }             
        } catch(Exception e) {
            log.error e
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to bind a property *before* the process of binding, You can create a custom [BindEventListener](http://grails.org/doc/latest/api/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/web/binding/BindEventListener.html) and register in the *grails-app/conf/spring/resources.groovy*

First of all, create your custom BindEventListener

**/src/groovy/SessionBinderEventListener.groovy**

```
import org.springframework.beans.MutablePropertyValues
import org.springframework.beans.TypeConverter

class SessionBinderEventListener implements BindEVentListener {

    void doBind(Object wrapper, MutablePropertyValues mpv, TypeConverter converter) {
        def session = RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes().getSession()
        mpv.addPropertyValue("company", session.company)
    }

}
```

Second of all, register your BindEventListener

**grails-app/conf/spring/resources.groovy**

```
beans = {
    sessionBinderEventListener(SessionBinderEventListener)
}
```

**However**, if your domain class does not hold a property called company, you will get [InvalidPropertyException](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/beans/InvalidPropertyException.html). To overcome this issue, create a list of classes which contain a property called *company* - See details bellow

**/src/groovy/SessionBinderEventListener.groovy**

```
import org.springframework.beans.MutablePropertyValues
import org.springframework.beans.TypeConverter

class SessionBinderEventListener implements BindEVentListener {

    private List<Class> allowedClasses = [Foo]

    void doBind(Object wrapper, MutablePropertyValues mpv, TypeConverter converter) {
        if(!(allowedClasses.contains(wrapper.class))) {
            return
        }

        def session = RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes().getSession()
        mpv.addPropertyValue("company", session.company)
    }

}
```