# Grails: tags that supports data binding?

Tags: grails

Are there any tags that support databinding other than select? . I use it for one to many relationships

It seems impractical if you have lots of data and scrolling will be longer

It would be awesome if its just a list of checkboxes then there will be a pagination

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`g.select` is just Grails default, but you can customize the view and use any element, since the information is there. Example:

```
class Parent {
  String name
  static hasMany = [childrens: Child]
}

class Child {
  String name
}

class ParentController {
  def create() {
    Parent parentInstance = new Parent()
    List<Children> childrens = Children.list()
    [parentInstance : parentInstance, childrens: childrens]
  }

  def save() {
    def childrens = params.list('childrens')
    println childrens //will output all checkbox marked...
  }

}

form.gsp

<ul>
<g:each in="${childrens}" var="child">
  <li><g:checkBox name="childrens" value="${child in parentInstance.childrens}" /></li>
</g:each>
</ul>
```

Some key points here:

- You may reconsider this approach if your `hasMany` side can have a lot of records;
- All your checkboxes must have the same name to be considered as a list;
- When updating the Parent you need to delete the relations before adding the new ones;

Related topic: [Grails - Simple hasMany Problem - Using CheckBoxes rather than HTML Select in create.gsp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2806101/grails-simple-hasmany-problem-using-checkboxes-rather-than-html-select-in-cr)